# Calculating "working time" using TimePeriod.NET's CalendarPeriodCollector gives unexpected results

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to calculate a due date for a service level agreement, and at the same time, I also need to back calculate the service level agreement in the other direction.

I've been struggling with calculations for "working time" (i.e. the time that work is possible during a set of days), and decided to use a third party library called [TimePeriodLibrary.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) for the task. I need to be able to do two things:

- Given a start `DateTime` and a `TimeSpan`, you should receive a `DateTime` of when a service level agreement date is due (date due).
- Given a start `DateTime` and an end `DateTime`, you should receive a `TimeSpan` of how long that service level agreement should take.

All source code (test project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/benpowell/TimePeriod.Net.Tests)). I have a `ServiceLevelManager` class that does all the work. It take a list of `WorkDays` and `HolidayPeriods`, in order to work out which hours are available to be worked. The `CalendarPeriodCollector` class is giving unexpected results. The expectations that do work in determining the due date from a timespan, do not calculate correctly when I back calculate them.

Can anyone see whether I am doing something wrong, or whether the library has a bug?

```
namespace ServicePlanner
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Itenso.TimePeriod;

    public class ServicePlannerManager
    {
        public ServicePlannerManager(IEnumerable<WorkDay> workDays, IEnumerable<HolidayPeriod> holidays)
        {
            this.WorkDays = workDays;
            this.Holidays = holidays;
        }

        public IEnumerable<WorkDay> WorkDays { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<HolidayPeriod> Holidays { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan GetRemainingWorkingTime(DateTime start, DateTime dueDate)
        {
            var filter = new CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter();
            foreach (var dayOfWeek in this.WorkDays)
            {
                filter.CollectingDayHours.Add(new DayHourRange(dayOfWeek.DayOfWeek, new Time(dayOfWeek.StartTime), new Time(dayOfWeek.EndTime)));
            }

            foreach (var holiday in this.Holidays)
            {
                filter.ExcludePeriods.Add(new TimeBlock(holiday.StartTime, holiday.EndTime));
            }

            var range = new CalendarTimeRange(start, dueDate);
            var collector = new CalendarPeriodCollector(filter, range);
            collector.CollectHours();

            var duration = collector.Periods.GetTotalDuration(new TimeZoneDurationProvider(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC")));
            return duration;
            //var rounded = Math.Round(duration.TotalMinutes, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            //return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(rounded);
        }
    }
}
```

The Unit tests that are failing are extracted below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ServicePlannerManagerTest
{
        [Test, TestCaseSource("LocalSource")]
    public void GetRemainingWorkingTimeWithHolidayShouldOnlyEnumerateWorkingTime(DateTime startTime, TimeSpan workingHours, DateTime expectedDueDate, string expectation)
    {
        // Arrange
        var workDays = new List<WorkDay>
        { 
            new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Monday, new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0)),
            new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0)),
            new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Wednesday, new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0)),
            new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Thursday, new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0)),
            new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Friday, new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0)),
        };
        var holidayPeriods = new List<HolidayPeriod>
        { 
            new HolidayPeriod(new DateTime(2015, 9, 15, 00, 0, 0), new DateTime(2015, 9, 16, 0, 0, 0))
        };
        var service = new ServicePlannerManager(workDays, holidayPeriods);

        // Act
        var result = service.GetRemainingWorkingTime(startTime, expectedDueDate);

        // Assert - 
        Assert.AreEqual(workingHours.TotalHours, result.TotalHours, expectation);
    }

    protected IEnumerable LocalSource()
    {
        yield return
            new TestCaseData(
                new DateTime(2015, 9, 14, 9, 0, 0),
                new TimeSpan(23, 0, 0),
                new DateTime(2015, 9, 17, 16, 0, 0),
                    "5. Expected 23 hours of working time to end on the 17/09/2015 16:00. Monday to Thursday evening. Just short of 3 full working days by one hour. Tuesday is holiday.");
    }
}
```

Output of this test is

```
5. Expected 23 hours of working time to end on the 17/09/2015 16:00. Monday to Thursday evening. Just short of 3 full working days by one hour. Tuesday is holiday.

Expected: 23.0d
But was:  15.999999999944444d
```

I want to know if I am using the collector incorrectly, or if the collector has a bug.

Comment: Please add details for what precisely you mean by "do not calculate correctly".  Give example input, expected output, and actual output.  Thanks.

Comment: Also be aware that this particular library has had issues with DST and time zones in the past.  I see in their changelog that v1.7.0 made some accommodations for this, but there's very little in the way of documentation.

Comment: @MattJohnson The unit tests in the source code (Github) show the expectations. If you run the unit tests you'll see the ones that fail.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that when I can get some time. But in general, StackOverflow frowns on questions relying on external sites for the question to be complete.  Remember, the primary purpose of StackOverflow is to create a compendium of questions and answers that are useful to others - not just to help you find someone to debug your code.  If the question isn't both concise and complete, then it won't be much help to others and won't get many upvotes.

Comment: The better thing to do for StackOverflow would be to isolate a specific test that fails, and reproduce it with as minimal of code as possible.  Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then someone can answer with either what is wrong with your code, or what is wrong with the library.

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks for that. I thought I was just being useful. ;-) I have updated the question to include the failing tests.

Comment: Sure.... But don't forget "minimal".  You should reduce this to the few lines of code that don't give the result you expect.  :)   Also, I started looking, and I don't think the `CalendarPeriodCollector` does intersection.  It seems to only return ranges that are completely bound by the search critera.  You may want to try something like `TimeRange.GetIntersection`... (Not 100% sure on this one.)

Comment: @MattJohnson Should now be a single example. I've also stripped out all of the method comments. I'm not trying to intersect per se. I'm trying to enumerate all of the `TimePeriods` between dateStart and dateEnd. Holidays and non-working time need to be excluded from the total duration.

Comment: You should really give those poor employees of yours a lunch break! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a great library for solving a familiar problem.

**The best thing to do is to output the periods in the period collection to help you debug the problem.**

I've rewritten your test to use the base types in the examples from their documentation:

```
        [Test, TestCaseSource("LocalSource")]
    public void SO_GetRemainingWorkingTimeWithHolidayShouldOnlyEnumerateWorkingTime(DateTime startTime,
        TimeSpan workingHours, DateTime expectedDueDate, string expectation)
    {
        CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter filter = new CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter();
        filter.Months.Add(YearMonth.September); // only Januaries
        filter.WeekDays.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday); // 
        filter.WeekDays.Add(DayOfWeek.Tuesday); // 
        filter.WeekDays.Add(DayOfWeek.Wednesday); // 
        filter.WeekDays.Add(DayOfWeek.Thursday); // 
        filter.WeekDays.Add(DayOfWeek.Friday); // 
        filter.CollectingHours.Add(new HourRange(9, 17)); // working hours

        CalendarTimeRange testPeriod = new CalendarTimeRange(startTime, expectedDueDate);//new DateTime(2015, 9, 14, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(2015, 9, 17, 18, 0, 0));
        Console.WriteLine("Calendar period collector of period: " + testPeriod);

        filter.ExcludePeriods.Add(new TimeBlock(new DateTime(2015, 9, 15, 00, 0, 0), new DateTime(2015, 9, 16, 0, 0, 0)));

        CalendarPeriodCollector collector = new CalendarPeriodCollector(filter, testPeriod);
        collector.CollectHours();

        foreach (ITimePeriod period in collector.Periods)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Period: " + period); // THIS WILL HELP A LOT!
        }
        var result = collector.Periods.GetTotalDuration(new TimeZoneDurationProvider(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC")));

        Console.WriteLine(result);
            //
    }
```

This results in:

```
Calendar period collector of period: 14/09/2015 09:00:00 - 17/09/2015 15:59:59 | 3.06:59
Period: 14/09/2015 09:00:00 - 14/09/2015 16:59:59 | 0.07:59
Period: 16/09/2015 09:00:00 - 16/09/2015 16:59:59 | 0.07:59
15:59:59.9999998
```

**So what I've noticed is that the very last period is missing.**

If you change the end time of your period from 4PM to 6PM (and therefore expect an extra hour = 24) it will just about pass. (you will also need to round the result)

So it looks like the periods need to be completely covered by the total duration, partial coverage is not counted. You may be able to change the options of the library, alternatively you may be able to add each hour of the working day as separate CollectingHours (hacky)

Hope that gets you closer to the answer you need!

Comment: Sorry  @Matt Johnson - seems like you had already figured this out in the comments. I hadn't expanded them all out to see it. Post your answer and Junto should accept it in place of mine.

Comment: So it appears to be a bug in the TimePeriodLibrary.NET then? Source code isn't available on a public repository sadly to try and issue a pull request.